# FBX Export behaviour with Lights

Tags: export, lighting, .fbx

I have a client who wants their scenes to be plug and play in Maya V-Ray which has been a headache. My main issue is that area lights in Blender have a custom property for it's x and y size while maya just uses scaling of the Light object.

Now you could scale the light in Blender but on export from Blender as an FBX the Lights lose all their scale values and end up as 1m planes. Weirdly enough when reimporting into Blender for whatever reason the Light would end up with a [1,1,1] scaling but 0.25m in the Area Light -> Rectangle Property.

Am i missing something here to force scale on lights? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: I am not using Maya or know how FBX treats an _Area Light_, but you are not really missing something, it is just that in Blender an _Area Light_ and also other objects have properties which give them their initial shape and size and these properties can be transformed, i.e. moved, rotated and scaled - but that does not change the actual property. Like a mesh object which might have a scale of [1, 1, 1] but that does not mean that the mesh is simply a cube of 1 m on each side. Scaling in _Object Mode_ is a non-destructive transformation, even for an _Area Light_.

Comment: Just tried export and re-import of an _Area Light_ as FBX. Actually here the light does not end up as an _Area Light_ with _Rectangle_ property. The exported _Area Light_ was _Rectangle_, size 4 m × 1.5 m. Re-importing it does not import an _Area Light_, it is a _Point Light_. I have to manually switch it to _Area_ and then it's set to _Square_ (not _Rectangle_) and 0.25 m - now this is simply the default which you get when you add a _Point Light_ in a Blender scene and change it to _Area_. Which means, FBX obviously cannot handle any of the properties and so you get a default _Point_ lamp.